# How to tidy up and reinforce a hole drilled in a sleeper

Tags: woodworking, metal-cutting, sheet-metal

I've just drilled a 28mm hole through a sleeper to put through a water irrigation pipe. Now I would like to somehow make it tidy and hopefully also prevent the edges of the hole. I was thinking a small square metal plate, with a 28mm hole that i could just screw on top of drilled hole on both sides of the sleeper, could do the job. Any thoughts if such a fitting exists, what is it called and where to find it? Any other ways to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: "prevent the edges of the hole." What do you want to prevent the edges of the hole from doing?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. A sleeper, by definition, doesn't have spans and shouldn't need reinforcement. Please revise to describe the problem better and/or show us a photo.

Comment: `drilled a 28mm hole through a sleeper` ... it would make more sense to say what material you drilled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to prevent abrasion of the irrigation pipe on the rough edges of the drilled hole, try looking for a *grommet* or a *bushing*:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use a round rasp/file (some call it a "rat-tail" file) to smooth/debur and round off the edges of the hole(s).